# How to setup a Java Language Server with Qt Creator?

Tags: java, qt, qt-creator, language-server-protocol

I can't find any information about the way I should configure the Java Language Server in Qt Creator (for android development, if it matters). I've found two repos with the language servers: by [@georgewfraser](https://github.com/georgewfraser/java-language-server) and [eclipse](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls), but I have no idea how to set them up.

I've tried to follow [this](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/may/article4.php) instruction, but it doesn't work neither.

Is it possible to setup a java language server in Creator? I know that it is possible for Python, but I can't find any information about Java.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you make any progress or find further information?

Comment: @SyntaX Unfortunately, no. I just gave up and did my stuff as it is. Nevertheless, I'm still interested in the solution. Please, tell me if you find something.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently configuring Qt for Android.
To add a Java language server to the Qt Creator IDE:

1. Add a new Java language server in the Qt Creator IDE (Tools > Options > Language Client > Add > New Java Language Server) (follow [this guide](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-language-servers.html)).
2. [Download](https://download.eclipse.org/equinox/) the latest release of equinox launcher (for me, it was 4.21).
3. Open ‘plugins’ subdirectory in the downloaded archive and search for org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_version.jar (in my case, it was org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.300.v20210813-1054.jar).
4. Copy this file into the directory of your preference. You can rename it like ‘startup.jar’.
5. Set up the path in the Qt Creator IDE (Tools > Options > Language Client > Add > New Java Language Server) to this equinox launcher file and click 'Apply'.

I need to test this solution as I am just starting my mobile project. I will update my response in case my solution does not work.

Read more about equinox launcher at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher

Comment: Do you managed to make it work?